# Calculate the angle between two triangles in CUDA

Tags: c, geometry, cuda, nvidia, triangulation

I wanted to calculate the angle between two triangles in 3D space. The two triangles will always share exactly two points. e.g.

Triangle 1:

```
Point1 (x1, y1, z1),  
Point2 (x2, y2, z2),   
Point3 (x3, y3, z3).
```

Triangle 2:

```
Point1 (x1, y1, z1),  
Point2 (x2, y2, z2),  
Point4 (x4, y4, z4).
```

Is there a way to calculate the angle between them efficiently in CUDA?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to define *"degree between them"* for me - do you mean the angle between their respective planes?

Comment: yes, between respective planes

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that each triangle shares *two* points, seems rather obvious now...

Comment: Not clear what this has to do with Cuda.   You can code Cuda kernels in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each plane, you need to construct it's normal vector (perpendicular to all lines in that plane).  The simple way to do that is to take the cross-product of two non-parallel lines in the triangle.  (ex  (P3-P1) **X** (P2-P1) and (P4-P1) **X** (P2-P1).

Normalize those.

The dot product of those two direction vectors gives you the cosine of the angle.

The tricky bit is to watch out for degenerate triangles!  If all 3 points defining either triangle are colinear, (that triangle is just a line) then what you're asking for is undefined, and the cross-product will divide by zero.  You need to decide what you're going to do in that case.

Since you're trying to do this on a GPU, you'll ideally want to write this function without any branches, if you're concerned about efficiency.  That would mean instead of testing for degenerate triangles with an `if` clause, you should try and do it with a ternary `A ? B : C`

Comment: Does the subtle difference between `if (A) {X = B;} else {X = C;}` and `X = A ? B : C` really affect GPU?

Comment: @Sasha.  This is just a general comment on GPU programming.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896422/cuda-avoiding-serial-execution-on-branch-divergence for details.  However, (a) if it's just a small loss of efficiency, you might not care, or (b) the CUDA compiler might be doing this optimization for you.

Answer (score 0):

The angle between the triangles is the same as the angle between the planes defined by the three points of each triangle.

Since both Point 1 or Point 2 lie in both planes, figure out the direction cosines from one of those points to Point 3, and then to Point 4.  Then, the cosine of the angle between these two lines is just the sum of the products of the corresponding direction cosines.

Comment: thanks, i know that no problem implementing it in ansi-c. but, what about cuda kernel?

Comment: Cuda supports C, doesn't it?  If so, just use their compiler and presumably it'll do a decent job...

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  In general P3-P1-P4 and P3-P2-P4 will give you two different angles and neither one is the angle between the two planes.

For example, let 
P1 = (1, 1000000, 0)
P2 = (1, -1000000, 0)
P3 = (0, 0, 0)
P4 = (0, 0, 1)